# Difference between self.element = 'this' and self.send("element=", 'this')

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I am trying to understand why these two things return different values.

Value is a `string`, and field is a `text_field`.

```
def populate_text(field, value)
  self.send "user_name=", value
end
# => nil

def populate_text(value)
  self.user_name = value
end
# => "value"
```

Why do `self` and `send` have different return values?

This class includes PageObject if that helps.

Comment: Can you include in your code the arguments you're calling each method with?

Comment: I can't reproduce the scenario you've described. See this gist: https://gist.github.com/jrunning/b9250c6d5af63192171e Both methods return the same value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure these two are exactly the same at the bytecode/VM level.

Comment: It must be something environment specific then, because it returns two different values for me.  I am using page-object too.

Comment: Why would you write `self.self "user_name=", value` instead of just `self.user_name = value`? `send` is primarily useful when the name of your field is dynamic.

Comment: I am new to programming/ruby and was just curious, I use self.user_name = value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby's syntax sugar for calling methods whose name ends with = always returns the righthand value, regardless of the return value of the method.

This is not the case when you use `send` to invoke the method. For example:

```
class Foo
  def bar=(n)
    :ohno
  end
end

f = Foo.new
x = (f.bar = 42)
y = f.send("bar=", 42)
p [x,y]
#=> [42, :ohno]
```

So, you would get two different values if your `user_name=` method has a return value that is not the argument to the method.

Comment: "This is not the case when you use `send` to invoke the method."

  Why?

Comment: The answer to "why" is "because that's how it's programmed". :) I don't know for sure why Matz et al did it this way, but it makes sense to me, so here's why **I** would have a programming language like Ruby do this: (1) Ruby allows chaining values to local variables, like `a = b = c = 17`. It would be a little weird if `a = b.c = d = 17` set `d` to `17` but `a` to something else. (2) But on the other hand, just because a method is named ending with `=` I don't want to change the return value normally. Invoking the method without syntax sugar I'd like to have a normal return value.

Comment: Why would it? Assignments always evaluate to the right hand side, method calls always evaluate to the return value of the method. That's a very simple rule. Why unnecessarily complicate it?

Answer (score -1):

Self.Send allows you to dynamically choose your objects, regardless of type.
This lets you data drive your test with very simple code.

Comment: I do not think this answers the question. The question was why two similar approaches returned different values. The asker already understood what `self.send` was for.